# SSL Error with wifi card on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, ssl

I just got a new Omen 15 without OS, I installed windows 10 but the wifi doesn't quite work. It connects to the wifi correctly, but most websites won't load, with the inspector console showing multiple ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. It will load the website, but not the JS or CSS needed. On the other hand some websites, mostly google.com, seem to be working.

Ethernet and USB work just fine, but no wifi network will, so I was thinking a driver problem? But I tried all recent drivers from both Intel and HP, with no luck. Could it be a hardware problem? How would I go about figuring it out?

It's a Ryzen 7 Omen 15 (Spanish model tho I'm in Italy?), with Intel AX200. Wifi driver 21.10.2.2. I'm not sure what other information could be needed but I'm very lost.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using the drivers that are installed by Windows by default,
and are missing specific drivers from HP.

As the Omen 15 has many sub-models (I found 18), I suggest going to
[HP Customer Support - Software and Driver Downloads](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/omen-by-hp-15-ax000-laptop-pc-series/10862325)
and use the "Detect my drivers" button for the website to detect your exact model
and list your drivers.

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't work. Do you think it could be an hardware issue?

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"? Can't it identify your model?

Comment: It's an OMEN Laptop - 15-en0003ns, it doesn't work as in it doesn't change anything (SSL errors on http requests, but only some of them)

Comment: Did you try [these drivers](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/omen-15-en0000-laptop-pc-series/32827270/model/34954921)? Are the SSL errors only on some specific websites (give examples)?

Comment: On most websites, seems to be those that make network requests themselves (JS/CSS). Here (https://paste.pics/CAW36) is a sample output, but really most websites are similar. Thye will either load and have empty content, or load but without CSS so unusable. Other non-browser things (e.g. Discord calls) work, while others (check for updates) won't

Comment: And yes I tried those drivers, I will now try to download them and try to see if safe mode changes anything, but it was a brand new laptop so doubtful it was some software conflict

Comment: Strange: Are you saying that you're getting ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on wifi but not on ethernet? Did you try other browsers (and which is your main browser)?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the problem. I'm not sure if the error is due to actual SSL or some other network problem. I tried multiple browsers and even reinstalled windows a few times, and am really lost right now

Comment: (1) Did you try to factory reset your router? (2) Is the router set to use WPA2
or WPA3? (3) You could try newer [wifi software](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/189347/intel-wi-fi-6-ax200-gig.html). (4) Try also to temporarily disable your security software.

Comment: Tried all of this already. I'm on WPA2 but I also tried an open network. Do you think it could possibly be a hardware problem?

Comment: It's certainly worth checking.

Comment: How would I do that without replacing the board? I actually think it's soldered on in this model

Comment: Sometimes two communication devices just don't work together. For the problem of ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, try first [this advice](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/fix-err-ssl-protocol-error/). Try also several different browsers.

Comment: Tried all of those from many different browsers